# How do I get my menu-bar not to go out of screen?

Tags: css, html, web, width

I have this website I'm making for my aunt.

I seem to have a problem with this menu.

When I put the browser on my 1920x1280 screen it's all perfect but when I put it on a lower resolution screen the menu bar goes out of screen on the right, but what is strange about this is is that my width is at 100%.

You can find the website here : [mathiasotw.be](http://mathiasotw.be/)

Thanks in advance.

**P.S.:** if you want the code i can post it . but normally u can see the code by right-clicking and inspecting it or pressing F12.

Comment: You  need to fix this for zoom in zoom out or resolution change..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have applied 20px padding for DIV with ID menu

change it to

```
padding:20px 0;
```

It should work for you.

Your new css should be looking like below:

```
#menu {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
box-shadow: 0 1px 6px black;
float: left;
height: 70px;
padding: 20px 0; // here padding was declared as 20px.
position: relative;
width: 100%;
z-index: 999;
}
```

I have not gone through your entire CSS file but seen these styles applied in firebug through #menu ruleset.